# Why do UWP apps not search any directories you have set in the PATH?

Tags: windows, uwp, path, powerbi

For instance the PowerBI program has a UWP version and a non-UWP version available to download direct from Microsoft. The UWP version does not search for DLLs in the locations set in the PATH. Why? Is there a way to force it to recognize the PATH variable without moving DLLs into the C:\Windows\System32 directory in order for to find the DLL?

It's the same with the UWP version of Excel.

A procom trace shows that anything in the PATH isn't searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do UWP apps not search any directories you have set in the PATH?

UWP app runs in the sandbox, I'm afraid you can't search the directories where in the locations set in the PATH.

> Is there a way to force it to recognize the PATH variable without moving DLLs into the C:\Windows\System32 directory

Currently, there is not good way to recognize the PATH variable, please try to use PowerBI desktop version.

Comment: Ok no problem. Yes the non-UWP works fine I just wondered why the other didn’t search the PATH. If it’s sandboxed then that explains it. Thanks.